# Powershell script to search mutiple remote PC's for specific files

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to run a powershell script from my PC against a txt file that contains numerous remote PC's.  I want to run a script against that list of PC's that will search a certain file path for specific file name and/or file extension.

I have been attempting to do a for each loop with my txt file inserted as a variable.  I am also attempting to get the file names returned to me via the cmdlet "Get-ChildItem."

I have not been able to get anything to work correctly so far.  Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?  Below are a couple of things I have tried so far...

**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $name= gc env:computername
$computers= get-content -path c:\users\person\Desktop\book2.txt
$csvfile = "c:\temp\$name.csv"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "C:\Users\*.locky"} 
export-csv -filepath $csvfile
```

**

*

```
Get-ChildItem : Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.
Parameter name: path2
At line:4 char:36
+ foreach ($computer in $computers) {Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "C:\Users\*.lo ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Windows\system32:String) [Get-ChildItem], Argume 
   ntException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Export-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'filepath'.
At line:5 char:12
+ export-csv -filepath $csvfile
+            ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

*

AND

```
C:\Windows\system32> ForEach ($system in (Get-Content C:\temp\Book2.txt))

if  ($exists in (Test-Path \\$system\c$\Users\*.locky))
{
    Get-Command $exists | fl Path,FileVersion | Out-File c:\temp\results.csv -Append
} 
At line:1 char:53
+ ForEach ($system in (Get-Content C:\temp\Book2.txt))
+                                                     ~
Missing statement body in foreach loop.
At line:3 char:14
+ if  ($exists in (Test-Path \\$system\c$\Users\*.locky))
+              ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At line:3 char:14
+ if  ($exists in (Test-Path \\$system\c$\Users\*.locky))
+              ~~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
At line:3 char:55
+ if  ($exists in (Test-Path \\$system\c$\Users\*.locky))
+                                                       ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingForeachStatement
```

Comment: `$name = $env:COMPUTERNAME` would be better than `$name= gc env:computername`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong `-filter` parameter in [`Get-ChildItem` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx). Next code snippet should work:

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {"\\$computer\C$\Users"|`
    Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter "*.locky"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for one of my customers today, and it worked great:

```
$servers = ("rds01-e","rds01-f","rds01-g")
$report = @()
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$server\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Library\*.xlam"
    $info = "" | Select ServerName, ExcelFile
    $info.ServerName = $server
    $info.ExcelFile = $files
    $report+=$info
    }
$report
$report | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\yep5.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You might prefer a hashtable, but depending on the PS version (3+), you can roll up PSCustomObjects into the $report array in a ForEach without needing to instantiate it separately. Some smarts have been baked in so it executes faster.

Comment: e.g.: 
`$report = Foreach (...) { $files = GCI (...); [pscustomobject]@{ Servername = $server; Excelfile = $files} }` 
For some objects, you might need to assign a variable name to the PSCustomObject and output that alone before the end of the foreach loop, but it's generally not neded. `$report = foreach (...) { $files = ...; $i = [pscustomobject]@{...} ; $i }`